# HTTP code when deleting records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I am using Ruby on Rails and I am trying to understand all the subtleties of HTTP codes to bring my app with standards, and I'm facing the following case.

Let's say I have a database with two tables, Companies and Employees.

- If users try to delete a company with no employee, it is deleted and server sends code 200.
- If users try to delete a company with employees, it is not deleted and server sends a message ("There are employees linked to this company..."). In this case, what code does server have to send ? I was thinking of HTTP 4XX but in my opinion, it is not a client error.

Comment: If they are trying to delete a resource that they are not allowed to, I'd say it was a client error. Make sure the client has that information by listing all allowable methods in the Allow: response header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **409 Conflict** error code. It indicates that the request could not be processed because of conflict in the request.

Once the employees are gone then the conflict is removed and the delete will work. You can think of it as a client error in the sense that it is a conflicted request from the client.

Comment: Indeed. It might also be a useful to include a Link header field indicating what resource the request was in conflict with.

Answer (score -1):

If the client is not allowed to use the DELETE method on companies with employees, I would suggest 405 Method not allowed. Include an explanation of why in the response body.

Comment: This is not what 405 is for.

Comment: Reference please? I would argue that if the resource was returned without DELETE in the Allow header then it is not only appropriate, it is optimal.

Comment: Allow/405 is for signaling what operations a resource supports, not whether it will actually perform it given the current state of the server.

See http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/changeset/2086 (and yes, that ticket had been open for years but Roy has finally resolved it).

Comment: That is true. In this case the service does not support DELETE on companies with employees. It is common for Web resources to allow different methods for different states. For example, PUT and DELETE would not be allowed without proper authentication.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated definition of status 405.

If a method isn't allowed because of missing authentication or missing permissions, the status code ought to be 401 or 403.

Comment: I hadn't read the latest definition. Thanks for the link. It makes sense, but I don't know if I like it. Allow should list all methods a resource could possibly be used under any circumstances even it the server knows the client is not authorized? That does not seem very informative. Does this mean the only way to know if a client is authorized is to attempt a prohibited request?